# In which episode of Golden Time did Koko say "I love you" to Banri on the school staircase?

Tags: golden-time

There was a sequence on the school staircase where Koko said "I love you" and Banri fainted. Which episode was that?

Comment: if you have all the episodes on your hard drive, you can extract the subtitle files from them using mkvtoolnix and then search the text for "love"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it was Banri that fainted not 2D-kun. As you can see, he's still standing on the top of the staircase. This happens in episode 7 at ~7:30-7:40

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Koko said she loved Banri in episode seven at about 7:25

Comment: any exact timings? guys come on this isn't yahoo answers